# Photoshop: how to fill a stroke with an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, stroke

I hope this is the right place to ask "how do I " questions. I've tried googling, but perhaps I'm not hitting on the right search words, or technique words.

I am trying to make a stroke, in this case of a triangle using the polygon tool, with a white "stroke line" and a transparent inner, ie no solid inside colour. I then want to fill the outline of the triangle with an image. I've found a tutorial to do a similar thing with text in illustrator, but the stroke itself seems to be different. If it were anything else I would select the area, and use the stamp tool, but I can't seem to select the area of the line section of the stroke.

Can any one suggest ways to do this?
I'm trying to re-create the image below, with different line fillers. 
Thanks.[image: Triangle]

Answer (score 3):

- Three layers:

  - *BACKGROUND*
  - *IMAGE*
  - *TRIANGLE* (fill= none, stroke= black)
- Hide the *IMAGE* and *BACKGROUND* layers
- From the **Channels Panel** > press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> Mac / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Win and click in a channel to load the *TRIANGLE* transparency selection
- Hide the *TRIANGLE* layer and activate the *IMAGE* one
- Click on the **Mask Icon**
- **Menu Image** > **Adjustment** > **Invert**
- Show the *BACKGROUND* layer

  [image: MASK]

Answer (score 0):

- add your image as a separate layer
- press <kbd>P</kbd> and draw your triangle shape, or paste from Illustrator as a 'Path'
- press <kbd>A</kbd> and select the entire triangle shape, right click and choose 'Create Vector Mask'
- also see: [How to use a shape as a vector mask?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73831)